# How to find number of ring homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know about ring homomorphism and some properties of ring. I got stuck into a problem which was asked in TIFR 19. The number of ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ to $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+x+1)$ is __ ? Please help me. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to get started: A ring homomorphism is uniquely defined by where it sends a set of generators for the domain. The domain here is $\Bbb Z[x, y]$ and a set of generators is $\{1, x, y\}$. How many possibilities are there for where you can send those three elements?

Comment: Is R.H.S. has $2^3=8$ elements?

Comment: @RiteshKhan Yes, $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+x+1)$ has $8$ elements.

Comment: So, is the number of homomorphism $8^3= 2^9?$

Comment: @RiteshKhan Not quite. Yes, that's the number of different ways to send $1, x$ and $y$ into $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^3+x^2+x+1)$. But not all of those become homomorphisms.

Comment: Are you tellingthat in **a homomorphism of rings**  you can send **the unit element** $1$ In $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ to **any** of the $8$ elements in the right hand side??? @RiteshKhan

Comment: Yeah. But how can I get rid of from those which are not homomorphism?

Comment: @RiteshKhan Instead of getting rid of the ones which aren't homomorphisms, I would focus on just finding the ones that are. One of the great things with polynomial rings (like $\Bbb Z[x, y]$) as homomorphism domains is that the different generators do not interact in any way. So you can take each generator separately and consider "how many places can I send this generator without breaking any homomorphism requirements?" instead of having to think "If I send this generator here, how many places can I send that generator without breaking any homomorphism requirements?"

Comment: @Arthur the unit element goes to the unit element under a ring homomorphism, so $x,y$ can be mapped to either of the 8 elements in the RHS ring, so should the answer be $8^2=64$ ?